# C - dynamic memory allocation using double pointer

Tags: c, pointers, memory-leaks, memory-management

I am allocating some memory in a function name myalloc() and using and freeing it in main().
I am using double pointer to do this, here is the code which works fine,

```
//Example # 1

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void myalloc( char ** ptr)
{
    *ptr = malloc(255);
    strcpy( *ptr, "Hello World");
}

int main()
{
    char *ptr = 0;
    myalloc( &ptr );
    printf("String is %s\n", ptr);
    free(ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

But following code does not work and gives segmentation fault. 
I think this is another way to use double pointers.

```
//Example # 2

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void myalloc( char ** ptr)
{
    *ptr = malloc(255);
    strcpy( *ptr, "Hello World");
}

int main()
{
    char **ptr = 0;
    myalloc( ptr );
    printf("String is %s\n", *ptr);
    free(*ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Please clarify me, why it is giving me seg fault in second example.

Note: Language = C,  Compiler = GCC 4.5.1, OS = Fedora Core 14

Also, i know that there are some question already been asked related to memory allocation using double pointers, but they don't address this issue, so please don't flag it as repetitive question.

Comment: What's foo? Is it supposed to be myalloc?

Comment: In both example, i forgot to replace foo() with myalloc().. my apologies..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
char **ptr = 0;
*ptr = malloc(255);
```

tries to write the pointer returned by `malloc` to the address(of type `char*`) pointed to by ptr. The address turns out to be ... `0`, which is not writable memory.

`ptr` should point to an address you can write to. You can do one of the following:

```
char *stackPtr; // Pointer on the stack, value irrelevant (gets overwritten)
ptr = &stackPtr;
// or
char **ptr = alloca(sizeof(char*)); // Equivalent to above
// or
char **ptr = malloc(sizeof(char*)); // Allocate memory on the heap
// note that ptr can be 0 if heap allocation fails
```

Comment: @phihag.. your first solution is similar to my first example, right? and other 2 solutions are pretty acceptable, thank you.

Comment: @mannan Yes, it's your first example, sans initializing the pointer which gets promptly overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

```
char **ptr = 0;
foo( ptr );
```

You are passing the value that ptr points to. But you havent pointed ptr to anything yet.

```
*ptr = malloc(255);
```

Now you are assigning some memory to that "nothing". So this wont work, and will segfault.
Why are you saying that this is another way of using double pointers? I apologise if I am wrong, but I guess you worked with type of program in Turbo-C earlier?

Comment: I think double pointers can be declared in 2 ways, char **ptr and char *p = &(char *), am i right?

Comment: mannan: there are two problems here. The first is that there is no such thing as a "double pointer" - that terminology is ambiguous. You are speaking of a pointer-to-pointer type. The second problem is that the type of a variable is what you declare it to be, and has nothing to do with how you set its value. `char *p = ...` declares and initializes a pointer to a char, no matter what is on the right-hand side of `=`. `char **ptr` declares a pointer to a pointer to a char.

Comment: The very notion of double pointer is confusing. The line that you wrote : `char **ptr = 0;` makes no sense in the first place. A pointer to a pointer does what it is called : you use it to pointe to some pointer. Hence, in order to use it, you have to have a valid pointer to which it can point to. You were not doing that in your example. I hope I am making sense.

Comment: Use a pointer to pointer when you actually need it; not just for the sake of using it. That was a typical behaviour in my college (in India). The very reason that I asked you about Turbo-C was that it used to accept all such assignments instead of providing a segfault.
If you are using it in order to learn it, then @Karl explained its usage very well.

Answer (score 0):

In the second case, you are passing the value of main's `ptr`, which is 0 (NULL), to `myalloc()`'s `ptr`. `myalloc()` then tries to dereference its null pointer, `ptr`.